# How to destruct a Kotlin list into sublists?

Tags: list, kotlin

How can I destruct a list in Kotlin into two sublists? Currently I do something like this:

```
val (first, rest) = listOf("one", "two", "three")
```

But doing so, first is "one" and rest is "two". I want them to be `first =["first"]` and `rest = ["two", "three"]`.

Is this even possible using this "destructor" syntax?

Comment: Nope, Kotlin doesn't use the head/tail paradigm of FP languages. On your own list type you could define your own `component0` and `component1` methods with the behavior you want, though. But the head/tail idiom is useful in tail-recursive functions, which aren't really the way you should write Kotlin code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) translates to calling `component1`, `component2`, etc. operator functions on an object. In the case of a `List`, these are defined as [extensions in the standard library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/component1.html), and return the Nth element respectively.

---

You could define your own extension extension that splits the list as desired and returns a `Pair`, which can then be destructured:

```
fun <T> List<T>.split() = Pair(take(1), drop(1))
```

This could be used like so:

```
val (first, rest) = listOf("one", "two", "three").split()

println(first) // [one]
println(rest)  // [two, three]
```

Perhaps naming it something better than `split` would be smart though.

Comment: I had virtually the same thing typed out except mine was just called "destructure". :) Good one.

Comment: To a lisp programmer first and rest are known as car and cdr, resp. Or you could call it headAndTail(), I guess...

Answer (score 7):

You could also define your own component functions:

```
operator fun <T> List<T>.component2(): List<T> = this.drop(1)
```

And then this works as expected:

```
val (head, rest) = listOf("one", "two", "three")
println(head) // "one"
println(rest) // ["two", "three"]
```

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this approach is that component3, component4, etc. Will still give you the 3rd and 4th element

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions). Here's my take:

```
val <T> List<T>.tail: List<T>
    get() = subList(1, size)

val <T> List<T>.head: T
    get() = first()

fun <T> List<T>.headTail() = Pair(head, tail)
```

First I'm defining the [extensions properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties) `head` and `tail` so you can do:

```
val list = listOf("one", "two", "three")
println(list.head) // "one"
println(list.tail) // ["two", "three"]
```

(If you don't like having the extension properties you can simply inline the code in the `headTail` function)

Finally the `headTail` function can be used like this:

```
val (head, tail) = listOf("one", "two", "three").headTail()
println(head) // "one"
println(tail) // ["two", "three"]
```

Notice that I'm using `subList` for the *tail* instead of `drop(1)` to prevent copying the list every time.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible by creating `component2` operator as extension method manyally:

```
operator fun <T> List<T>.component2(): List<T> = drop(1)

fun destrcutList() {
    val (first: String, second: List<String>) = listOf("1", "2", "3")
}
```

You need create extension method only for `component2`, `component1` will be used as previously.

Types can be omitted:

```
fun destrcutList() {
    val (first, second) = listOf("1", "2", "3")
    println(second[0]) // prints "2"
}
```

One important note: in case if you declare extension method in another package **you have to import function manually**:

```
import your.awesome.package.component2
```